# Is it common for Vietnamese people to be able to split apples in half with their bare hands?

Tags: behavior

I've seen this rumor online a few times now, such as:

> [*Can Vietnamese people break apples in half?*](https://findanyanswer.com/can-vietnamese-people-break-apples-in-half) (1,247 views)
>
> Yes. Source: half Vietnamese.

The claim also seems to be on Reddit ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VietNam/comments/7s6mop/how_do_all_of_you_rip_apples_in_half/); [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VietNam/comments/7s5kp4/so_whats_the_deal_with_ripping_apples_in_half/); [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/VietNam/comments/5jlvy4/are_you_vietnamese_and_can_you_rip_an_apple_in/)) [I can't access Reddit from China right now: VPN is not working].  For this rumor, there's something special about Vietnamese people in particular; it's more than just "some people can do it, and some people are Vietnamese".

**Question**: Is it common for Vietnamese people to be able to split apples in half with their bare hands?

Comment: I have seen people do that (in Belgium) while I was young, in the 1950s.

Comment: If there is "something special about Vietnamese people" in this regard, it seems likely to be something as simple as "the trick happens to be popular in Vietnam, and therefore more Vietnamese people choose to take the time to learn how to do it".

Comment: It might also depend on what varieties of apple are popular in different countries. Different varieties vary in softness, so perhaps Vietnamese apples are more amenable to the trick in some way, in addition to cultural factors as @NateEldredge suggests

Comment: I've seen people do it in the US.  You need the right apple, though.

Comment: If you google "Vietnamese apple splitting," it seems apparent that this is an easy trick that's popular in Vietnam, but can be done by anyone (and that some apples are better than others).  However, it's also apparently known and understood well enough that there are few scholarly sources on the subject.

Comment: I have done this myself a few times. Splitting an apple with your hands is one of those things that looks nearly impossible but is actually not that hard if you have a reasonably decent grip strength and you know the technique.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I also think that it may needs to be more focused. The Reddit discussions suggest an unusual association between this party trick and Vietnamese people – the claim that "oh yes, everybody in Vietnam knows how to do _that_, but don't ask why" is a recurring theme. The claim doesn't seem to be that this isn't something that nobody else can (so it's not that "there's something special about Vietnamese people"), but rather that it's a trick that most Vietnamese know how to do, and that they as well as others have notice that this is rather unusual.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've successfully split an apple in half after reading the Reddit posts even though I'm not Vietnamese.

Comment: Maybe it's something about Vietnamese _apples_?

Comment: Splitting apples is the common way i eat them. No Vietnamese connection. You need a bit of grip strength, the rest is technique (and some apples will not yield)

Comment: As Bob Mortimer demonstrates: ["The thumbs are used for gripping, not for ripping"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F21mTojMCAc)